# can i create this kind of linked list in c?

Tags: c, linked-list

i am just learning about linked lists and i wrote this code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct linkedList
{
    char name[100];
    struct linkedList *next;
};

struct linkedList *head = NULL;


void main()
{
    struct linkedList *node1,*node2;

        node1 = (struct linkedList*)malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
        strcpy(node1->name, "aaa");
        node1->next = NULL;
        head = node1;

        node2 = (struct linkedList*)malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
        strcpy(node2->name, "bbb");
        node1->next = node2;
        node2->next = NULL;
}
```

I cant understand is this a valid linked list ??
Do i have to create the same "node" name ? or i can use "node1" "node2"?
in my mind what i wrote is equal to :
head---->|"aaa"|addr_to_node2|---->|"bbb"|NULL|
is it true ??
how can i print this linked list ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your understanding is correct. And you loop over a list with... a loop. :) What you do in the loop body is up to you, but calling `printf` may be an alternative. :)

Comment: You are correct so far. But imagine if you have to add, say, 10K nodes to the linked list. How will you implement it with this approach?

Comment: yea but i just wanted to learn the general idea... what is the correct why to do it ? write a loop that adds nodes recursively ?

Comment: Of course it's not a linked list - it's a program! (one that happens to create a linked list when you run it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here how you can print the link list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct linkedList
{
  char name[100];
  struct linkedList *next;
};

struct linkedList *head = NULL;


int main()
{
    struct linkedList *node1,*node2;

    node1 = (struct linkedList*)malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
    strcpy(node1->name, "aaa");
    node1->next = NULL;
    head = node1;

    node2 = (struct linkedList*)malloc(sizeof(struct linkedList));
    strcpy(node2->name, "bbb");
    node1->next = node2;
    node2->next = NULL;
    while(node1!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",node1->name);
        node1 = node1->next;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: why do you write while(node1!=NULL) and not                                      while (node1->next != NULL) ?

Comment: isnt this way of printing destroying node1 ?? what if i want to use this list again?? why do i realy need the head node if i dont use it her?

Comment: If you use node1->next!=NULL then the iteration breaks before printing the last name. And yah this destroys the linked list. If you want to use later the iterate the linked list through a dummy node. Hope you understand. :)

Comment: someting like:                                                                                      temp = node1;

 while (temp!=NULL)
 {
  printf("%s\n", temp->name);
  temp = temp->next;
 }                                                                                                                i think i got it , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is valid.

> Do i have to create the same "node" name ? or i can use "node1" "node2"?

You can use any name as it is a regular variable.

Actually, struct you created is not a linked list, but a linked list node. A node contains information and pointer to next node, while list itself should contain pointer to head node and to tail node (for fast insertions)
Also, consider adding functions for adding and removing items from this list.